# Component Metadata Inner Xml is not well formed

Tags: 2011, event-system

In the Metadata Design of a Component I have the following structure as displayed in the image below:

[image]

Inside my Event System, I am fetching the `component.Metadata.InnerXml`, the XML returned shows as follows:

```
<metadata xmlns="TVShow">
    <activation_date>2012-06-03T11:31:42</activation_date>
    <expiration_date>2014-06-03T11:31:48</expiration_date>
    <notes>test</notes>
</metadata>
<distribution_start_date xmlns="TVShow">2013-08-13T10:00:51</distribution_start_date>
<distribution_end_date xmlns="TVShow">2015-08-13T10:00:58</distribution_end_date>
```

Which is breaking my code as I'm expecting this XML to only contain one root element. Therefore I assume the XML is not well formed. What can be the resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that what "inner" XML means? Anyway - this situation is quite common. The usual solution is simply to add your own element to contain it.

Comment: That is right meaning of inner xml. Yes I can add my own element.

Answer (score 3):

`Component.Metadata` returns an [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x97ek538%28v=vs.100%29), so on there you should have both an [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml%28v=vs.100%29) and an [`OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml%28v=vs.100%29) property.

The [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml%28v=vs.100%29) property returns you the markup representing just the children of this node as a [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.100%29). That is well formed XML, but cannot be considered an [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.100%29). If you want to process it as an [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.100%29), you will either need to wrap it inside a root element, or use the [`OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml%28v=vs.100%29) property.

Depending on what you want to do with the contents, you can also use an `ItemFields` Collection like this:

```cs
ItemFields metadata = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);
if (metadata.Contains("distribution_start_date"))
{
    DateField distributionStartDateField = (DateField) metadata["distribution_start_date"];
    DateTime distributionStartDate = distributionStartDateField.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OuterXml` property and not `InnerXml`. `InnerXml` is not showing the node itself

Comment: I am not seeing any such property "component.Metadata.OuterXml"

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.

```
if (component.Metadata["distribution_start_date"] != null)
{
    distributionStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(component.Metadata["distribution_start_date"].InnerText);
}
if (component.Metadata["distribution_end_date"] != null)
{
    distributionEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(component.Metadata["distribution_end_date"].InnerText);
}

if (component.Metadata["metadata"]["activation_date"]!=null)
{
    activationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(component.Metadata["metadata"]["activation_date"].InnerText);
}
if (component.Metadata["metadata"]["expiration_date"]!=null)
{
    expirationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(component.Metadata["metadata"]["expiration_date"].InnerText);
}
```